# Why does Eclipse XML validation produce erroneous errors? Is there a fix?

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, validation

I have many Spring projects in my Eclipse workspace.  Occasionally they are all validated without errors. However, sometimes various Spring config XML files show errors like:

- `cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'`
- `cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.`
- `Referenced file contains errors(http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xssd). For more information, right click...`

I can resolve the errors by simply opening the file, right-clicking and choosing 'Validate'.  This will cause the XML validator to re-validate the file and the errors will disappear.  I have also cleaned the whole workspace and allowed eclipse to rebuild/revalidate everything and sometimes they go away.

However, if the project is refreshed and the validation re-runs, many times the error will re-appear.

Does anyone know why this happens? I don't believe there is really an error in the XML file. Is there a trick to help the XML validator avoid getting confused?

Here is the beginning of one of the files exhibiting some of these errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd"
   default-autowire="byName">
```

Comment: Are these all in your XML Catalog? Do you have intermittent network problems?

Comment: It is hard to rule out intermittent network problems, I haven't noticed anything like that though.  What do you mean by XML Catalog?